# Reading Bytes in Python from Bluetooth, encode problem

Tags: python, arrays, bluetooth-lowenergy, byte

I'm trying to get some values from bluetooth in Python, my problem basically is when I tried to read the data from bluetooth, in this two lines:

```
value = bytes(await connection.client.read_gatt_char(read_characteristic))
print(value)
```

it prints:
`b'\x91'`

I tried to use:
`valueprint = str(value).encode()`

But just printed me this:
`"b'\x91'"`

Then I tried `print("Value: {0}%".format(int(value[0])))`

But it gave me 145 which is not the value that I sent, I put a value 657 to run some test.

Comment: You need to show how you are creating `txChar`. In the reference you linked to it uses `BLEByteCharacteristic`. `BLEByteCharacteristic` is for sending a single byte. If you want to send byte arrays, use `BLECharacteristic` or `BLEUnsignedShortCharacteristic` to send an integer of two bytes.

Comment: I updated the post, it is my full code in Arduino. I'm a beginner using this library so if yo can help me with this. It would be amazing.

Comment: I don't have the correct Arduino board to test this but from looking at the documentation I would have thought using `BLEUnsignedShortCharacteristic txChar(uuidOfTxChar, BLERead);`  would be the only line that needs change. As a side note, the UUIDs used for the custom service and characteristics are in the reserved range used for officially adopted services. More details at: https://www.novelbits.io/uuid-for-custom-services-and-characteristics/